# Validate unique() only on owned models

Tags: laravel, validation, relationship

Let's say I have a User model and a Brand model, with a one-to-many relationship between them:

User model:

```
public function brands()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Brand::class);
}
```

This means different users can have different brands with the same name without conflict.

Now, I want to make a validation rule for creating brands, but ONLY for the user's owned brands, in such a way that is not possible for a user to have two brands with the same name.

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you  want to do it in the model/repository part, simplu run

```
$exists = (bool)$user->brands()->where('name', '=', $newBrandName)->count();
```

if `$exists` is true, you prevent him from adding the new brand since the name is used

if you want to do it in the validator part use the rule

```
'name' => Rule::unique('brands')->where(function ($query) {
    return $query->where('user_id', auth()->id());
})
```

be carefull for hidden dependancy.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thnks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public function rules()
{
    $user = \Auth::user(); // get the user

    return [
        'name' => [
            Rule::unique('brands')->where(function ($query) use ($user) {
                $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
            }),
        ],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I found in [Laravel Document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#rule-unique)

```
Validator::make($data, [
    'name' => Rule::unique('brands')->where(function ($query) {
        return $query->where('user_id', $user_id);
    })
]);
```